# Можно ли указать behaviors для модуля?

Tags: yii2

Есть модуль modules/admin/Module.php

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module {
    public function init() {
        parent::init(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно задать разрешения ему, чтобы например ограничить доступ определенным пользователям?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться этой библиотекой https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin